# Haskell fromSing and Sing typing/kind errors

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-platform

I'm trying to write some Haskell code to represent a negative binomial distribution in an existing library (HLearn). From what I can tell HLearn requires that model parameters (in this case the r value for the negative binomial distribution) be input as type level natural numbers in the typeclass representing the distribution. My problem is that I am getting a kind related error when I try to use sing to access the runtime value of the parameter.

The relevant code is commented

```
-- | Negative binomial distribution

{-# LANGUAGE
    GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
    TypeFamilies,
    DataKinds,
    KindSignatures #-}

module HLearn.Models.Distributions.Univariate.NegativeBinomial
    (NegativeBinomial
    )
    where

import GHC.TypeLits

import HLearn.Algebra
import HLearn.Models.Distributions.Common
import HLearn.Models.Distributions.Univariate.Internal.Moments

newtype NegativeBinomial (r::Nat) prob dp = NegativeBinomial { moments :: (Moments3 dp)     }
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord, Monoid, Group)

instance (Num dp) => HomTrainer (NegativeBinomial r prob dp) where
    type Datapoint (NegativeBinomial r prob dp) = dp
    train1dp dp = NegativeBinomial $ train1dp dp

instance (Num dp) => Probabilistic (NegativeBinomial r prob dp) where
    type Probability (NegativeBinomial r prob dp) = prob

-- The function in question
negbin_p :: (SingI r, Integral dp, Fractional prob) => NegativeBinomial r prob dp ->  prob
negbin_p (NegativeBinomial moments) = ((fromIntegral $ m0 moments)/(fromIntegral $ m1  moments)) * rval
    where
        rval = fromSing (sing :: Sing r) -- This is the code that is reported as causing errors
```

The errors I get are:

```
src\HLearn\Models\Distributions\Univariate\NegativeBinomial.hs:33:24:
Could not deduce (SingE * (Kind *) prob)
  arising from a use of `fromSing'
from the context (SingI Nat r, Integral dp, Fractional prob)
  bound by the type signature for
             negbin_p :: (SingI Nat r, Integral dp, Fractional prob) =>
                         NegativeBinomial r prob dp -> prob
  at src\HLearn\Models\Distributions\Univariate\NegativeBinomial.hs:30:13-89
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (SingE * (Kind *) prob)
In the expression: fromSing (sing :: Sing r)
In an equation for `rval': rval = fromSing (sing :: Sing r)
In an equation for `negbin_p':
    negbin_p (NegativeBinomial moments)
      = ((fromIntegral $ m0 moments) / (fromIntegral $ m1 moments))
        * rval
      where
          rval = fromSing (sing :: Sing r)

src\HLearn\Models\Distributions\Univariate\NegativeBinomial.hs:33:34:
Could not deduce (SingI * r1) arising from a use of `sing'
from the context (SingI Nat r, Integral dp, Fractional prob)
  bound by the type signature for
             negbin_p :: (SingI Nat r, Integral dp, Fractional prob) =>
                         NegativeBinomial r prob dp -> prob
  at src\HLearn\Models\Distributions\Univariate\NegativeBinomial.hs:30:13-89
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (SingI * r1)
In the first argument of `fromSing', namely `(sing :: Sing r)'
In the expression: fromSing (sing :: Sing r)
In an equation for `rval': rval = fromSing (sing :: Sing r)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you need [`ScopedTypeVariables`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables) and `negbin_p :: forall r. ...`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to luqui for pointing out ScopedTypeVariables. After adding that to the language pragma the updated, working code is the same except:

```
negbin_p :: forall r dp prob . (SingI r, Integral dp, Fractional prob) => NegativeBinomial r prob dp -> prob
negbin_p (NegativeBinomial moments) = ((fromIntegral $ m0 moments)/(fromIntegral $ m1 moments)) * rval
    where
        rval = fromIntegral $ fromSing (sing :: Sing r)
```